# How to use custom data in my chart on jsreport?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, jsreport

I am trying to make some charts with custom data in jsreport and using Chart.js, the problem is that i don't know how to use custom data to fill my chart with. So far, i created a very big json with my data and the function to generate the chart and place inside a canvas, but i can't call the function inside my html with the handlebars because it says the document is not defined. So, how can i use my data to create my charts and display it inside a canvas?

P.S.: I can easily display a chart with static data, but i really want to do this using the json that i created.

My function to create my chart:

```
function graficoEstiloAdaptado(exame){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('graficoEsquerdo').getContext('2d');

    var total = 280;
    var incentivador = 0;
    var idealizador = 0;
    var detalhista = 0;
    var sociavel = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<exame.respostas.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<exame.respostas[i].alternativas.length;j++){
            switch(exame.respostas[i].alternativas[j].categoria){
                case 'Incentivador':
                    incentivador += 4-j;
                    break;
                case 'Idealizador':
                    idealizador += 4-j;
                    break;
                case 'Detalhista':
                    detalhista += 4-j;
                    break;
                case 'Sociável':
                    sociavel += 4-j;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    var porcentagens = {
        incentivador: (incentivador/total).toFixed(1),
        idealizador: (idealizador/total).toFixed(1),
        detalhista: (detalhista/total).toFixed(1),
        sociavel: (sociavel/total).toFixed(1)
    };

    var chartEstiloAdaptado = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [porcentagens.incentivador + "%", porcentagens.idealizador + "%", porcentagens.detalhista + "%", porcentagens.sociavel + "%"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Gráfico I",
                data: [
                   porcentagens.incentivador,
                   porcentagens.idealizador,
                   porcentagens.detalhista,
                   porcentagens.sociavel
                ]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            animation: {
                onComplete: function() {
                    window.JSREPORT_READY_TO_START = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And i don't want to use an API to get the data yet, i just want to structure the report the way i like and after that use an API to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is described in this [blog](https://jsreport.net/blog/using-input-data-in-html-page-inline-javascript):

> Define helper function which makes JSON string from the parameter
>
> ```
> function toJSON(data) {
>   return JSON.stringify(data);
> }
> ```
>
> And call this helper in inline script
>
> ```
> <script>
>     var data= {{{toJSON this}}}
> </script>
> ```

The full example with chart.js can look like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id='myChart' style="margin-top:30px"></canvas>

    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'apples',
          data: {{{toJSON A}}},
          backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
        }, {
          label: 'oranges',
          data: {{{toJSON B}}},
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
        }]
      },
      options: {
            animation: {
                onComplete: function () {
                    // set the PDF printing trigger when the animation is done
                    // to have this working, the phantom-pdf menu in the left must
                    // have the wait for printing trigger option selected
                    window.JSREPORT_READY_TO_START = true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Working playground demo can be found [here](https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/SkcQLLOGl/187).

Comment: Thank you so much!